# symbolic links - case sensitivity

Tags: macos, symlink

I am having problems in a program trying to follow symbolic links, and tracked it down to an apparent case issue.

If I list the symbolic links it shows a target, but this does not exist.

```
ls -la "/User Guides And Information"
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  60 21 Mar 11:28 /User Guides And Information -> /Library/Documentation/User Guides and Information.localized
```

There is similar target, which differs only in the case of "And", which Finder seems to find OK.

```
ls -la /Library/Documentation
drwxrwxr-x  10 root  admin     340 21 Mar 11:28 User Guides And Information.localized/
```

Is there some character set issue, or is Finder ignoring case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on which OS and file system you are using, but yes, the native Mac file systems are typically case-insensitive.

Comment: Thanks. I had assumed HFS+ was case sensitive, like all the other ?NIX systems I have used.

Comment: The command line IS case sensitive, but the underlying FS is not. (This is in contrast to NTFS, where the FS is case sensitive, but the Windows environment is not)

Comment: HFS+ volumes are optionally case-sensitive: there are case-sensitive and case-insensitive variants available when you initialize an HFS+ file system.  The default is case-insensitive.  But code should not depend on that.